# Is the cons operation cons elements from right to left?

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence, syntactic-sugar, cons

We know `1:2:[]` will returns `[1,2]`.

I just tried `1:2`, this gives me an error.

```
<interactive>:48:1: error:
    ? Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    ? When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [a]
```

I know this may be not a proper example since the `:` operation cons an element and a list. But I'm just wondering how it works in `1:2:[]`

Comment: `(:)` **must** be right-associative because if `1:2:[]` was parsed as `(1:2):[]` it would create a type error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error message could be better. But `1 : 2` won't create list. You need:

```
1 : [2]
```

And `[2]` is a syntax sugar for `2:[]`.

So now you could deduce that `1:2:[]` is expanded into `1 : (2 : [])`. You can also discover this behavior by using `:info` command in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :info (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
```

It says that `(:)` operator is right associative.

Also, there exist `TemplateHaskell` trick which allows you to see how parenthesis will be specified in resulting expression:

```
$ ghci -ddump-splices -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude> $([| 1:2:[] |])  -- put expression with bunch of operators here
<interactive>:1:3-14: Splicing expression
    [| 1 : 2 : [] |] ======> (1 GHC.Types.: (2 GHC.Types.: []))
[1,2]
```